# how to keep a variable value on a prefab object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm spawning this object called "trash" repeatedly and I want it to progressively goes faster, but every time a new trash was spawned it went back to its initial speed.
how do I make the trash always use the progressive speed?

```
public class TrashScript : MonoBehaviour
{   
    float trashAcceleration = 2;
    float trashDespawn = -15;
    float trashInitialSpeed = 5;
    float trashProgressiveSpeed = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        trashInitialSpeed += trashAcceleration * Time.deltaTime;
        trashProgressiveSpeed = trashInitialSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.position += (Vector3.left * trashProgressiveSpeed);

        if (transform.position.x < trashDespawn)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code that's spawning the trash object

```
public class TrashSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject trash;

    public float heightOffset;
    public float spawnRate;

    private float timer = 0;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(timer < spawnRate)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            SpawnTrash();
            timer = 0;
        }
    }

    void SpawnTrash()
    {
        float lowestPoint = transform.position.y - heightOffset;
        float highestPoint = transform.position.y + heightOffset;
        Instantiate(trash, new Vector3(transform.position.x, Random.Range(lowestPoint, highestPoint), 0), transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

I tried creating a separate method for the progressive speed calculation but it didn't work

Comment: This is best handled from your trash controller.  Can you include the controller code that is spawning the trash prefabs.

Comment: If you want the speed to constantly be increasing, then the spawner should be controlling the speed.  If you want the speed increasing only while trash exists, keep the speed on the trash, and let the spawner get the speed from the current trash and set it on the new spawning trash.  Spawner also needs to know when the current trash is despawning so it can cache that speed (in the case that trash despawns before another spawns).

Comment: Before your TrashScript calls Destroy(gameObject) it should pass current speed to the TrashSpawner. Then in TrashSpawner.SpawnTrash() you must assign that speed to the next instantiated trash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could solve this without altering much code is by creating a reference float.  The idea is that the same reference is used for all trash instances, and that value is changed by the controller.  That reference is passed to each instance of trash so they all use the same value.

```
public class FloatRef
{
    public float value;
}
```

The spawner controls the value of this reference.

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TrashScript trashPrefab;

    private FloatRef floatRef = new FloatRef();
    private TrashScript trashInstance;
    
    private void Spawn()
    {
        trashInstance = Instantiate(trashPrefab, ...);
        trashInstance.SetFloatRef(floatRef);
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        // This condition makes it so the value only increases while trash exists.
        // If you want the value to change regardless of trash existing, remove this condition
        //
        if (trashInstance)
        {
            floatRef.value = GetNewFloatValue(); // Replace this function with your calculation
        }
    }
}
```

and the trash script simply uses the value

```
public class TrashScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private FloatRef floatRef;

    public void SetFloatRef(FloatRef floatRef)
    {
        this.floatRef = floatRef;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position += (Vector3.left * floatRef.value);  
  
        ...
    }
}
```